# How to get output from I/O manipulator in a string?

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S");
```

It outputs

```
01-03-2024 02-01-35
```

How can I assign that output to a string variable instead?

Comment: `auto todayDate = std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S");`?

Comment: Paddy, I know you meant well, but your edit came after my answer and now my answer looks really borked :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) to put (or insert) the time into a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) rather than to `std::cout`, and then you can get the string from the stream and save it to a variable.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);

    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S");

    std::string s = ss.str();

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: Neither the title nor the body of the question mentioned `string` when I wrote this.

---

The *type* [`put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) returns is *unspecified*. If you want to store it in a variable temporarily, you  may simply use `auto`:

```cpp
auto todayDate = std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S");
```

However, if you wish to create a type of your own where you have it as a member, it becomes slightly more complicated, but you can use `decltype` to get the actual type:

```cpp
struct my_type {
    using put_time_type = decltype(std::put_time(std::declval<std::tm*>(), ""));
    
    put_time_type todayDate;
};
```

and you can then use it as you wish:

```cpp
my_type ex;
ex.todayDate = std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S");
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture the formatted output into a string variable, you can use a string stream instead of `std::cout` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
  // Get current time
  std::tm* tm = std::localtime(nullptr);

  // Define format string
  const std::string format_str = "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S";

  // Create a string stream object
  std::stringstream ss;

  // Use put_time to format the time and write it to the string stream
  ss << std::put_time(tm, format_str.c_str());

  // Extract the formatted time string from the stream
  std::string formatted_time = ss.str();

  // Now you can use the formatted_time variable
  std::cout << "Formatted time: " << formatted_time << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In this code, we create a `std::stringstream` object (`ss`) and use `std::put_time` to format the time and write it to the stream. Finally, we call `ss.str()` to extract the formatted string and assign it to the `formatted_time` variable.